# How should I return "Observable/Flowable/Single" "onError" in nested code?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

I am developing an Android app using "RxJava", "Room", "Firebase (Firestore)" and "Kotlin".
It is based on MVP pattern.

I am the newbie of the RxJava, so I need a help...
It is very difficult for me...

The scenario is...
1. Presenter request a user to DAO (Local DB - Room)
2. DAO returns a user
 2.1 If a user doesn't exist, the Presenter request a user to Firebase (Firestore)
3. Presenter returns the user to View.

The codes are here:

[1] Dao

```
@Dao
interface PlayersDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE playerName = :playerName")
    fun getPlayerByName(playerName: String): Single<Player>
}
```

[2] Firebase

```
class FirebaseDataSource {
    private val mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun getPlayerByName(playerName: String) = Single.create<Player> { emitter ->
        mFirestore.collection(PLAYERS)
            .whereEqualTo("playerName", playerName)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                if (it.isSuccessful && !it.result.isEmpty) {
                    emitter.onSuccess(it.result.documents[0].toObject(Player::class.java))
                } else {
                    emitter.onError(PlayerNotExistException())
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[3] Presenter

```
fun getPlayer(playerName: String): Single<Player> {
    return Single.create { emitter ->
        playerDao.getPlayerByName(playerName)
            .doOnError {
                // When it failed to get the user from local, it should retry to Firebase.
                // But I don't know how should I cover this logic.
                Single.create<Player> { emitter2 ->
                    firebaseDataSource.getPlayerByName(playerName)
                        .doOnError {
                            Log.d(TAG, "getPlayerByName(firebase) - failed")
                        }
                        .doOnSuccess {
                            emitter.onSuccess(it)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .doOnSuccess {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getPlayerByName(local) - success")
                    emitter.onSuccess(it)
                }
    }
}
```

I don't know how should get and return the user when it failed to get the user from local db.

And "Single" is correct?
Should I use "Observable" or "Flowable"?

<<<------------------------ This is cleared by Ahmed Ashraf G.

Here is a continuous question.
I fixed code like below:

Presenter

```
fun getPlayer(playerName: String): Single<Player> {
    Log.d(TAG, "getPlayerByName - $playerName")

    return playerDao.getPlayerByName(playerName)
            .onErrorResumeNext {
                Log.d(TAG, "[BS] getPlayerByName(local) - onError: ${it.message}")
                playersFirebaseDataSource.getPlayerByName(playerName)
                    .doOnSuccess {
                        Log.d(TAG, "getPlayerByName(firebase) - success")
                        playerDao.savePlayer(it) // Here is run in "Main" thread
                    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }
}
```

> playerDao.savePlayer(it)

This code should be in background thread.
But it doesn't.
What should I do fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the "onErrorResumeNext" operator.
From the docs:

> onErrorResumeNext( ) — instructs an Observable to emit a sequence of items if it encounters an error.

so it might look something like this:

```
return playerDao.getPlayerByName(playerName)
         .onErrorResumeNext(firebaseDataSource.getPlayerByName(playerName))
```

This basically tries the DAO single, if it encounters an error, it switches to the FirebaseDataSource single.

EDIT: you can find other error handling operators in [Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)

EDIT 2: As for your second problem, you're right to use `observeOn` which will switch the work on a specific scheduler, but you also used `subscribeOn` that can be harmful and here is why, `subscribeOn` is only meant to be used once, it specifies the thread in which you'll "observe" the observable, it is usually used along with the `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`.

I recommend reading more about the subject through [Here](https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a)

Comment: Ahmed Ashraf G, I fixed it and I have an additional question.
Could you answer me, please?

Comment: @yoonhok yeah sure

Comment: I added the additional question on here, could you check this please?

Comment: Nice work figuring it out yourself :)
I've edited my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Really thank you :) You're comments are very helpful to me.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the continuous question, I fixed the code by myself.

```
fun getPlayer(playerName: String): Single<Player> {
    return playerDao.getPlayerByName(playerName)
        .onErrorResumeNext {
            Log.d(TAG, "getPlayerByName(local) - onError: ${it.message}")
            playersFirebaseDataSource.getPlayerByName(playerName)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // I added this two line
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())   // And it works fine.
                .doOnSuccess {
                    Log.d(TAG, "getPlayerByName(firebase) - success")
                    playerDao.savePlayer(it) // Now, here is run in the background thread!
                }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        }
}
```